# Execução do setTimeout com replaceWith

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Tenho o seguinte código que executa uma consulta na DB com ajax. Pelo que quando no success eu meto append em vez de replaceWith, a função resulta perfeitamente e executa a cada 5 segundos, mas quando introduzo o replaceWith no lugar do append, a função só executa uma unica vez e não executa o setimeout.

PS: as variáveis php aparecem assim porque a função está dentro de uma query php.

```
function fetchdata". $row2['id'] ."(){
    var dz='". $row2['id'] ."';     
    var dld='$jmmj';

 $.ajax({
 type: 'POST',
    data: {dz: dz},
  url: 'submit4.php',


  success: function(datas){
    if(datas!==''){
   $('#message18w". $row2['id'] ."').replaceWith(datas);


     }else{ $('#message18w". $row2['id'] ."').replaceWith('');}
     setTimeout(fetchdata". $row2['id'] .",5000);
  },
    error:function(datas){
   setTimeout(fetchdata". $row2['id'] .",5000);
  },
  complete:function(datas){
   setTimeout(fetchdata". $row2['id'] .",5000);
  }
 });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
 setTimeout(fetchdata". $row2['id'] .",5000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Tem um problema no seu código:

Você colocou um `setTimeout` dentro dos blocos "success", "error" e "complete", sendo assim, quando o Ajax retorna ok, vai chamar os 2 `setTimeouts` e vai causar um gargalo no seu servidor e até travar o navegador.

Você deve deixar o `setTimeout` apenas dentro do "complete", pois esse bloco sempre será chamado após o retorno do Ajax, dando erro ou não.

Comment: mesmo assim o problema persiste, esse setTimeout foi introduzido por mim na procura de uma solução

Comment: já resolvi o problema, nem se quer estava nesse trecho de código mas sim naquilo que eu metia como replace

Comment: Era isso que eu ia falar agora rs.. Que bom q resolveu! Boa sorte!